# How to checking value from dynamic substr then can be query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form-input with field PSB_CODE.
And NEW.PSB_CODE can be checking for parent PSB_CODE.
ex :

1. 111 => parent, level 1
2. 11101 => child 1, with 111 as parent, level 2
3. 11102 => child 2, with 111 as parent, level 2
4. 1110101 => child 3, with 11101 as parent, level 3

I would input PSB_CODE : 1110102 => but can be detect automaticly 11101 as parent when beforeSave. Maxlength for PSB_CODE is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to select the longest prefix from the list of already defined prefixes. For example,

```
$codes = array('111', '11101', '11102');

$new = '1110102';

$max = '';
foreach($codes as $code) {
    if(strpos($new, $code) === 0 && strlen($code) > strlen($max))
        $max = $code;
}

echo 'the parent is ', $max;
```

Comment: thanks @georg : Yes, great solution. Now, i try $codes is query from my table.